# No view found for id 0x7f0c0078 for the fragment while calling fragment from activity

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

In my app i have to call a fragment from activity. so that i am using Frgament mangaer. While i am running that code it throws the above exception.

this is my main activity

```
  public class UserDashBoardActivity extends DrawerActivity {


        private Context context;
        private ImageButton searchBtn;
        private ImageButton favBtn;
        private ImageButton profileBtn;
        private ImageButton reminderBtn;
        private ImageButton logoutBtn;
        private ImageButton notificationBtn;
        private ImageView seatchIcon;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        // slide menu items
        private String[] navMenuTitles;
        private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_dash_boad, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // delete the selected event from event list added here
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_notify:
                    return true;

                case R.id.action_favourite:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_navigation:

            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.user_dash_board);
            context = getApplicationContext();
            searchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
            favBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fav_btn);
            profileBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_btn);
            reminderBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reminder_btn);
            notificationBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notification_btn);
            logoutBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.logout_btn));
            final EditText Search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent regAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
                    // Clears History of Activity
                    regAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(regAct);
                }
            });

            favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
//here i am calling the fragment
                    MyFavouritesFragment fragment = new MyFavouritesFragment();


                    if (fragment != null) {
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                    }
                }
            });

            profileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent tabAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutCollegeFragment.class);
                    tabAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(tabAct);

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

this is my fragment to be called

```
public class MyFavouritesFragment extends Fragment {
    private FavouriteDelegates favouriteDelegates = new FavouriteDelegates();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Context context;
    private List<CollegeMO> collegeMOs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_favourites_list_view, container, false);
return view;

    }

    private class FavouriteCollege extends BaseAdapter {
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView collegeText;


            FavouriteCollege() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return collegeMOs.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            // show list values name and mobile number in contact page
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_favourites, null);
                collegeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clg_details);
                collegeText.setText(collegeMOs.get(position).getCollegeName());
                return convertView;
            }

        }
    }
```

this is my main activity xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/appblue"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchCollege"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/search_college"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-167dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fav_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myFavourites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="370dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:text="@string/my_favourites"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/profile_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/my_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/notification_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-165dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="390dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/notification"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reminder_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/reminder_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/reminder"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logout_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="410dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is fragment listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/course_detail_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the item of myfavourite listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/appblue">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clgImage"
            android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clg_details" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/downloadImage"
                android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Paste your Fragment class. Its missing.

Comment: now i added the code for your reference

Answer (score 0):

you dont have container (`R.id.container`) in your main activity xml where you should display your fragment into.

like

```
<framelayout android:id="@+id/container"/> // this snippet is just for idea.
```

Comment: if i add that code the layout opened but it was to small and it opend under the main activity

Comment: you can set your container height width to display properly and of course it will under main activity . fragment should have parent activity . they are not independent in that way.

Comment: ohk @vijayg try that and let me know.

Comment: that page displayed under main activity only it has not displayed at full screen how to solve this

Comment: i have changed may main activity xml in above code thats my xml

Comment: you all control have constant value try to give you container match parent temporary and check . and please go through how to place layout in android development first.